# Ionic, How to get current user wordpress role?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, ionic4, wordpress-rest-api

actually I want to use it in userpage.html like this:

---

```
<span *ngIf="GetCurrentUserRole == 'Subscriber' ">
          <p>You are Subscriber</p>
</span>
<span *ngIf="GetCurrentUserRole == 'Editor' ">
          <p>You are Editor</p>
</span>
```

---

Does someone knows How to make these codes works?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the current user role with AngularJS or with PHP?

Comment: Thanks @Tokant, it definitely not with PHP, the file that only I can write are .ts and .html